# OctoberCMS Builder plugin with state and suburb

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins, october-form-controller

I have created two plugins (**States** and **Suburbs**) using [Builder](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder) plugin and so far it works great.

The Thing is, in **States** plugin, I am simply allowing ability to add state names and in Suburbs plugin, I am allowing users to **select State** first and then enter **suburb name**. All works fine as of now in these two plugins.

Now the thing is, I have a third plugin called as **Properties** in which I have both these 2 drop-downs **State** and **Suburb** but as of now All States and All Suburbs are showing. But I want users to select first **State** and then based on state selection it should should all its suburbs to my another **Suburb** drop-down.

I have tried to use **dependsOn** which Builder plugin provides but I just am not able to understand the flow to achieve it step by step based on the current scenario I have. Below is the code what I have done and tried so far.

**plugins\technobrave\properties\models\Property.php**

```
<?php namespace Technobrave\Properties\Models;

    use Model;
    use technobrave\states\Models\State as State;
    use technobrave\suburbs\Models\Suburb as Suburb;

    public function getStateIdOptions()
        {
            // getting all states 

           $get_all_states = State::all();


           $fields[''] = 'Select any State';
           foreach ($get_all_states as $current_state) {
                $fields[$current_state->attributes['id']] = $current_state->attributes['state_name'];

           }
          ksort($fields);  
          return $fields;
        }    



        public function getSuburbIdOptions($stateId)
        {
            // getting all suburbs 

            $get_all_suburbs = Suburb::all();

            $fields[''] = 'Select any Suburb';
            foreach ($get_all_suburbs as $current_suburb) {
                $fields[$current_suburb->attributes['id']] = $current_suburb->attributes['suburb'];

            }       


          ksort($fields);  
          return $fields;
        }
    }
```

How can I do this from here on ? Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated and useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys,

Eventually I have come up with a solution. Here is what I have done.

**fields.yaml** File:   **technobrave\properties\models\property\fields.yaml**

```
        state_id:
            label: 'State:'
            span: auto
            required: 1
            type: dropdown
            tab: 'Address Information'
        suburb_id:
            label: 'Suburb:'
            span: auto
            required: 1
            type: dropdown
            tab: 'Address Information'
            placeholder: 'Select any Suburb'
            dependsOn: state_id
```

As you can see above,

In `suburb_id` I have added, below two lines of code.

```
placeholder: 'Select any Suburb'
dependsOn: state_id
```

**Property Model** File: **technobrave\properties\models\Property.php**

```
use Model;
use technobrave\states\Models\State as State;
use technobrave\suburbs\Models\Suburb as Suburb;

public function getStateIdOptions()
    {
        // getting all states 

       $get_all_states = State::all();


       $fields[''] = 'Select any State';
       foreach ($get_all_states as $current_state) {
            $fields[$current_state->attributes['id']] = $current_state->attributes['state_name'];

       }
      ksort($fields);  
      return $fields;
    }    



public function getSuburbIdOptions()
{
    return Suburb::getNameList($this->state_id);
}
```

Here above, I have just updated **getSuburbIdOptions** method with below code and removed my old code.

```
return Suburb::getNameList($this->state_id);
```

Then I went to my **Suburbs** plugin.

**Suburb Model** File: **technobrave\suburbs\models\Suburb.php**

And in this model file, I have made sure to use `belongsTo` and added **getNameList** method like below.

```
 <?php namespace Technobrave\Suburbs\Models;

    use Model;
    use technobrave\states\Models\State as State;
    /**
     * Model
     */
    class Suburb extends Model
    {

        /**
         * @var string The database table used by the model.
         */
        public $table = 'youtable_here_';


        public $belongsTo = ['State' => [
                                                      'technobrave\states\Models\State',
                                                      'key' => 'state'
                                                  ],

                            ];


        /**
         * @var array Cache for nameList() method
         */
        protected static $nameList = [];

        public static function getNameList($stateId)
        {
            if (isset(self::$nameList[$stateId])) {
                return self::$nameList[$stateId];
            }

            return self::$nameList[$stateId] = self::wherestate($stateId)->lists('suburb', 'id');
        }

    }
```

And it works.

Hope it will help to those who stuck on the same issue/implementation.

Thanks